# Animate div toward cursor when cursor is near, and then animate div back to original position when cursor is far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm looking to recreate what these websites have. The divs seem to move toward the mouse, when the mouse is near, but then they move back to their original position when the move moves away.

Heres some examples of it: https://www.clapat.com/ (their menu) 
and http://twotwentytwo.se/ (their logo)

I'm not sure where to start with this, so any information would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Source code for _clapat_ doesn't seem to be minified so it is easy to copy their design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with the below example.
Try to use jQuery Animate, CSS3 and create what you require.

```js
$(".movable").mousemove(function(e){
    $("#image").stop().animate({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```

```css
#image{
  text-align:center;
}
.movable:hover #image{
  position:absolute;
}
.movable{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="movable">
  <img id="image" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-icon-part-2/128/menu-256.png" width="40px"/>
</div>
```